# jQuery function combined with php-loop input

Tags: php, jquery, loops, dynamic, iteration

I'm building a table full of input-fields out of a php while-loop:
Time 1 (ID=begin)
Time 2 (ID=end)
Saldo (ID=saldo)   <---  this is Time2-Time1

The user should be able to see how many hours the saldo before submitting the formular, so I'm calculation the saldo by jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function calculate() {
var time1 = $("#begin").val().split(':'),
time2 = $("#ende").val().split(':');
     var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
         hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
         mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
         mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
     var hours = hours2 - hours1, mins = 0;
     if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
     if(mins2 >= mins1) {
         mins = mins2 - mins1;
     }
     else {
         mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
         hours--;
     }
     mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
     hours += mins;
     hours = hours.toFixed(2);
     $("#saldo").val(hours);
 }
 $("#begin,#end").change(calculate);
 calculate();
});
```

It works as long there is only one pair of 'begin' and 'end'. As soon as there are more pairs generated by the loop it's broken - the reason is simple: the id's are not unique any more.

But how can I use this useful jQuery-function as a general one, working together with the table generated by the php while-loop?
So that it's showing the saldo1, saldo2, saldo2 for each pair end1-begin1, end2-begin2 etc...  ...

Any possibilities about using filters or a class, iteration/second loop?

Thx a lot!